# Targeting specific class when there are more than one element with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to get the content of a specific class but more than one class with the same name. Let's take as an example class `box_nag`. I can the first class of that name by:

```
document.getElementsbyClassName("box_nag")[0].textContent
```

And the second class by:

```
document.getElementsbyClassName("box_nag")[1].textContent
```

However, I *think* it would be better to take into account also numbers, in this example `1` and `2`:

**h1** class="box_nag"

**h2** class="box_nag"

How do I do that in JavaScript?

```
<h1 class="box_nag"><a href="/wydanie/0,20119.html">
                Polityka - nr 44 (3083) z dnia 2016-10-26; s. 15-18</a></h1>
<h2 class="box_nag"><a href="/dzial/polityka,0,356.html">Polityka</a></h2>
```

Comment: You're looking for `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` which will let you look for any valid CSS selector, e. g. `document.querySelectorAll('h1.box_nag')`

Comment: You can try `h1.box_nag` or `.h2.box_nag`

Comment: @SeanVieira You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and combine the class name with the tag name ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/8ds5z14b/) in case the service is down):

```js
document.querySelector('h1.box_nag').style.color = 'red';

document.querySelector('h2.box_nag').style.color = 'green';
```

```html
<h1 class="box_nag">H1</h1>

<h2 class="box_nag">H2</h2>
```

Comment: Plain and simple but I needed to use  querySelectorAll. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you could do it this way:

```
$('h1.box_nag').html();
$('h2.box_nag').html();
```

.html() returns the contents of the element you have selected, including html tags, if you would like just the value, use .val() instead.

Comment: I need to use JavaScript and not jQuery. BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: hehe it was probably Ori Drori

Comment: @AlanSutherland - nope. I'm a strong believer in not using -1 :)

Comment: @OriDriori I'll give your answer a +1 for that. menteith I gave the jQuery solution for future readers of this answer if they want to use jQuery instead